# `anchor build` failing

Tags: anchor

I'm trying to build program with `anchor-build` and it's returning `Failed to install sbf-tools: HTTP status client error (404 Not Found) for url (https://github.com/solana-labs/sbf-tools/releases/download/v1.32/solana-bpf-tools-osx.tar.bz2)`. I'm releasing the latest release of solana which is `1.15.2`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the installation instructions for the SBF tools [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/sbf-tools). If you're on Linux then it should be enough to simply run the `build.sh` script given there locally. Read the instructions in the readme for installation in other environments

Comment: I'm on macos m1. I've tried cloning the repo and running `./build.sh` but it errored - `realpath: out: No such file or directory
+ OUT_DIR=`

Comment: And besides, I have a similar folder in `~/.cache/solana` with name `v1.33`.

Comment: You'll need v1.15.2. Try downloading it manually from [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases?page=1) and run the `env.sh` script. If you can't get that to work, consider using the stable releases. Those all still depend on sbf